# Why does reading from a video block when using multiprocessing?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, opencv, python

I'm trying to read a video file using cv2 within a process as shown below. Reading blocks at the beginning without displaying any frame!!!

I ensured opening the video file using `reader_1920_1080.isOpened()`!!
It blocks at `self.reader_1920_1080.read()` and doesn't continue to next line of code, which doesn't help me to check `success`.

When I tried running without `multiprocessing`, it works perfectly!!

As such, the problem is in reading within a process!!

**Any solution?**

```
import cv2
from multiprocessing import Process

class ComputePSNRProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ComputePSNRProcess, self).__init__()
        self.reader_1920_1080 = cv2.VideoCapture('res_1920_1080.ivf')


    def run(self):
        while True:
            success, original_1920_1080 = self.reader_1920_1080.read()
            cv2.imshow('original', original_1920_1080)
            cv2.waitKey(25)


computePSNR = ComputePSNRProcess()
computePSNR.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't execute `cv2.VideoCapture` in the master process and use it in the child process.

I am not sure, but I think the reason is that `cv2.VideoCapture` locks an OS resource, that cannot be passed to other process.

Running your code in Windows 10, I am getting an exception:

> can't pickle cv2.VideoCapture objects

In the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53308334/python-multiprocess-cant-pickle-opencv-videocapture-object), Dan Mašek recommends to create the `VideoCapture` instance in run method.

---

Other issues:

- When working with processes, you must use `if __name__ == '__main__':` ...
- For clean finish, you need to break the loop when `success` is `False`.

The following code sample supposed to work:

```
import cv2
from multiprocessing import Process

class ComputePSNRProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ComputePSNRProcess, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        self.reader_1920_1080 = cv2.VideoCapture('res_1920_1080.ivf')

        while True:
            success, original_1920_1080 = self.reader_1920_1080.read()

            if not success:
                break

            cv2.imshow('original', original_1920_1080)
            cv2.waitKey(25)

        self.reader_1920_1080.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    computePSNR = ComputePSNRProcess()
    computePSNR.start()
```

Comment: Thank you..Why with processes, must use if __name__ == '__main__'?

Comment: See Process class [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class). "For an explanation of why the if `__name__ == '__main__'` part is necessary, see [Programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming)."